# Get the Special Character from URL

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Url is like That:

```
http://localhost:620251/Default.aspx/?group=Bkgbdsconsumer & Retailmailinglist
```

Want the group value on cs page:

```
Bkgbdsconsumer & Retailmailinglist
```

I ma doing this:

```
string group= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["group"]);
```

Comment: Key `group` has value `Bkgbdsconsumer ` and `Retailmailinglist` is an another key.

Comment: I need the QueryString value  Bkgbdsconsumer & Retailmailinglist

Comment: `&` is *not* a special character. It's the *parameter separator*. Your URL contains a `group` parameter with the value `kgbdsconsumer ` and an parameter named ` Retailmailinglist` without a value.  If you want your URL to contain this character you'll have to *URL Encode* it first, eg with `Uri.EscapeDataSting`

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary that's not a query string. That's the second half of the first parameter and a second parameter. *Encode the group value*, don't pass it like this

Comment: Actully i am having a search where i searched by group one group name is  Bkgbdsconsumer & Retailmailinglist but from querystring i am only getting Bkgbdsconsumer and i want the same whatever i passed in url @apocalypse

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary the problem is the code that generates the parameter. Post *that* code.

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary please don't repeat the same thing. Your ULR is bad. The code that produces it is bad. Post that code

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary a *valid* URL would look like `http://localhost:620251/Default.aspx?group=Bkgbdsconsumer%20&%20Retailmailinglist`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  i know this this my url should like this but whatever group value i have i just paste in url and hit it

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary post the code that generates this URL. It's broken. Fix it. Use `Uri.EscapeDataString` **before** you append the `group` value to it. Once you fix the bug in your code, `Request.QueryString["group"]` will work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Bkgbdsconsumer&Retailmailinglist  there is no space before and after &

Comment: you must use `%26` instead of `&` as `&` is used to indicate `url` parameters. refer [HTML URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more details.

Comment: @Arvindchaudhary there is, in the URL you posted. Either that, or you didn't copy the URL correctly. The problem is `&` not the spaces.There's no point arguing that you want to read that or that it's OK. It's not. No browser or URL parsing method will accept that. Fix the faulty code, don't try to cover up the problem. BTW the port nubmer `620251` is invalid too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Ok, as I thought, there is no space before and after `&` in your URL.

Also port number is too big `620251` (max is 65535 as I think).

```
// 'fixed' port number
string url = @"http://localhost:12345/Default.aspx/?group=Bkgbdsconsumer&Retailmailinglist";

Uri myUri = new Uri (url);

var groupValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (myUri.Query)["group"];

string[] allKeysWithoutValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString (myUri.Query).GetValues (null);
```

Now `allKeysWithoutValue` is an array with one element `Retailmailinglist`.

Comment: If the keys were correct, there would be no problem extracting the `group` value. The URL is invalid.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: what is invalid in his url?

Comment: `&` is the *parameter separator*. This means the URL contains *two* parameters. One named `group` and one named ` Retailmailinglist`. The *keys* are `group` and ` Retailmailinglist`

Comment: Actually if you use `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` you get `group` and `null` for the keys

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: and what's wrong about that? (except spaces before and after &, which it think is his typo)

Comment: I don't understand the downvote at all.